# How to configure Key for IdentityServer4 on Linux

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, security, ssl-certificate, identityserver4

I have an asp.net core app with IdentityServer4. **In production it requires a key.**

On Windows Server, I deployed it OK - created a self-signed certificate and added `LocalMacine/my` as the key location.

How can I do the same on Linux?

`appsettings.json` config on Windows - **need syntax for Linux:**

```
  "IdentityServer": {
    "Clients": {
      "MyDemoApp": {
        "Profile": "IdentityServerSPA"
      }
    },
    "Key": {
      "Type": "Store",
      "StoreName": "My",
      "StoreLocation": "LocalMachine",
      "Name": "CN=my-demo"
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you not just refer to your certificate as a .pfx file using a appsettings file like:

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Https": {
        "Url": "https://identityservice.local:6001",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "identityservice.local.pfx",
          "Password": "changeit"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, when I deploy IdentityServer as a Linux container, I store my certificate in Azure Key Vault.

Comment: I forgot abt this question.. I resolved it differently. Idk if what you are saying would work in my case but ok anyway

Comment: How did you resolve it differently @BoppityBop? Please define if you can as other people (myself included) may be looking for answers to this issue

Comment: Also, how do you use the Endpoints example provided within the identity server area of appsettings @tore-nestenius?

Comment: @user3105469 in my case I add the physical certificate file inside the container and then ASP.NET core will at startup configure and add the certificate. In my example it is for local development and I have created a local trusted and signed develoment certificate that maps to identityservice.local and I have configured my hostfile to map the domain identityservice.local to 127.0.0.1

Comment: My issue that I have with that is that the certificate is located in another directory outside of the public_html area where the asp.net core 6 solution is depoyed. The certificate is located in "cert" which lies on the same level as "public_html". Note, we are talking Linux CentOS hosting here.



"IdentityServer": {   
    "Key": {
      "Type": "File",
      "FilePath": "../cert/My-certificate.pfx",
      "Password": "LongTrickyPassword"
    }
  },

Error: System.InvalidOperationException: No signing credential is configured by the 'IdentityServer:Key' configuration section.

Comment: in my answer above, I am talking about the HTTPS certificate, not the signing key. The signing key is a separate key that IdentityServer needs. obviously, the CERT should not be reachable from the public internet (not inside wwwroot).  You can use the var rsaCert = new X509Certificate2("certpath/name.pfx", "cert-password"); method to load a cert into memory and then add it to IdentityServer.

Comment: Great input @ToreNestenius! Thanks! It turns out the tips mentioned did also work in my case, however, I was having issues with the service not updating properly, hence getting problems no matter what I tried ;)